# Cannot continue rebase because of: Could not execute the todo command

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am trying to rebase from master, after executing `git rebase master` I get returned:

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten
> by merge:
> client/src/components/ui/organisms/Sidebar/customItems/payoutsBatchItems.tsx
> Please move or remove them before you merge. Aborting hint: Could not
> execute the todo command hint:  hint:     pick
> eadc11822d3455ef87da803ba2037c090a2e4e80 fixing mistake hint:  hint:
> It has been rescheduled; To edit the command before continuing, please
> hint: edit the todo list first: hint:  hint:     git rebase
> --edit-todo hint:     git rebase --continue Could not apply eadc1182... fixing mistake

The issue is also that payoutsBatchItems.tsx in my MR has the correct name `PayoutsBatchItems` and not `payoutsBatchItems` (capital P) I am not sure how to solve this. Any clues ?

Comment: There's not enough information here to provide a complete answer. My first question would be, how did untracked files show up in your repo during a rebase? Also, what steps did you take before rebasing? Did you verify that the working directory was clean before the rebase? If you add `--interactive` to your rebase command, does it look the way you would predict? Or, in what way is it unexpected?

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward solution would be to abort the rebase, rename the file, and redo the rebase:

```bash
git rebase --abort

git mv payoutsBatchItems.tsx PayoutsBatchItems.tsx
git commit -m "Rename file to correct case"

git rebase master
```

See if that is enough for you to complete the rebase.